# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: username. Starting .net application

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, global-asax

When I start the application from Visual Studio 2010  the following error shows up:

> *Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: username*

I can see this error in `Global.asax.cs` in the parameter sender of this method:

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

The problem is that I'm not using username anywhere and my web.config

```
    <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MYSQL"
             connectionString="Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=server_name;Database=database_name;uid=my_user_id;pwd=my_pwd"
             providerName="System.Data.Odbc"/>
      </connectionStrings>
      <system.web>
         <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
      </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Any help will be welcome.

**EDIT:**

More information:

What I can see is:

```
sender.base.Profile.base.base.Session = '((System.Web.HttpApplication)(sender)).Session' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
```

and

```
sender.Profile.base.LastActivityDate = '((System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase)(((ASP.global_asax)(sender)).Profile)).LastAct‌​ivityDate' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException'
```

and

```
sender.Profile.base.LastActivityDate.base = {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: username"}
```

**EDIT**

This code works without any problem, and also I can execute queries.

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYSQL"].ConnectionString;
        OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection(ConnStr);
        con.Open();
        con.Close();
     }
```

Comment: you should find right line where it fails, try to debug. Application_Error is a place where all unhandled exception come. try to look into StackTrace

Comment: Check your connection string. According to http://connectionstrings.com/mysql when you use `Driver`, you should use `User` and `Password` instead of `uid` and `pwd`.

Comment: I debugged and the error is the next step after Application_Star.

Comment: That's not possible - you must be trying to connect to the DB _somewhere_. The application wouldn't try to connect to the DB without some code to do so - where is it? What's the first line of code you expect to hit the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this error only happens when I run the application from Visual Studio and not when it is deployed in IIS.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is malformed.

It should probably be:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver};Server=server_name;Database=database_name;User=my_user_id;Password=my_pwd
```

`User` instead of `uid` and `Password` instead of `pwd`.

See [connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com/mysql) for the different options.

Comment: I checked and I have connection with the database, so I think that this is not the problem. If I write the suggested parameters I still have he same error.

Comment: @fiso - Did you check the full stack trace? Perhaps there is an exception that is being swallowed somewhere in your data access classes?

Comment: @fiso - Please edit the _question_ and add details to it. Comments are not a good place for lots of text.